# My variable is saved in the URL/Location, how do I read it from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I'm creating a little website and I have a variable made in javascript which is assigned through a script.

```
var alias = "";
```

After the alias is assigned a value, it is displayed in the URL/Location like so:

```
file:///C:/TEST/TEST/Desktop/Website/main.html?alias=Jordan
```

Is there a way to read the variable from another page, so when the page redirects it can say:

> Hello 'Jordan'!

I think I heard somewhere that this was possible, but I never knew how!

Also: Is there a way to carry this variable accross MULTIPLE pages without using localstorage/cookies etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use PHP to access those variables

You could use a simple `$_GET['alias']` then to get the string "Jordan"

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use GET to accomplish this.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

or depending on the language you are using, each dynamic language has a GET method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$_GET['alias']` simply

---

with JavaScript

```
function getQueryVariable(variable){
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

getQueryVariable('alias'); // usage
```

Source http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Comment: Would this work after you've loaded a new URL and your var is no longer part of the url/location?

Comment: @JordanChillMcgeeLudgate no both are dependent on `URL` .